# Two separate mpirun on a single slurm job

Tags: sockets, slurm

I would like to use two sockets of a node, for two separate *mpirun* on single job submission, like this:

```
socket    ---- 0 ----                      ---- 1 ----   
core     0 1 ... 14 15                   0 1 ... 14 15
task   mpirun#1 with 16 process      mpirun#2 with 16 process
```

Also, I want to run with no multithreading.

Therefore, here is what I put in the Slurm header file:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1 
#SBATCH --sockets-per-node=2 
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=16 
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=1
```

Please help me to understand what should I put in []:

```
mpirun [something1]  python code_1.py &
mpirun [something2]  python code_2.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out `mpirun` on its own, cannot allocate cores of a single socket exclusively, when there are more sockets available.

The solution is to use `numactl` along with mpirun to imply the desired policy:

```
mpirun -np 16   numactl --cpunodebind=0  python code_1.py &
mpirun -np 16   numactl --cpunodebind=1  python code_1.py &
wait
```

does the job as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-npersocket` or `--npersocket #number` or `--map-by` in `mpirun` command.

`man mpirun` gives the following:

```
 -npersocket, --npersocket <#persocket>
              On each node, launch this many processes times the number of
              processor sockets on the node.  The -npersocket option also turns on
              the -bind-to-socket option.  (deprecated in favor of --map-by
              ppr:n:socket)

--map-by <foo>
    Map to the specified object, defaults to socket. Supported options include slot, hwthread, core, L1cache, L2cache, L3cache, socket, numa, board, node, sequential, distance, and ppr. Any object can include modifiers by adding a : and any combination of PE=n (bind n processing elements to each proc), SPAN (load balance the processes across the allocation), OVERSUBSCRIBE (allow more processes on a node than processing elements), and NOOVERSUBSCRIBE. This includes PPR, where the pattern would be terminated by another colon to separate it from the modifiers.
```

You could try something like this:

```
mpirun -n 16 -npersocket  python code_1.py &
mpirun -n 16 -npersocket  python code_2.py
```

or
you could try with the option `--map-by ppr:16:socket`. This will map 16 processes to a socket. Also to stop oversubscription use `--no-oversubscribe`.

```
mpirun -n 16 --map-by ppr:16:socket --no-oversubscribe python code_1.py &
mpirun -n 16 --map-by ppr:16:socket --no-oversubscribe python code_2.py
```

You can also use `-report-bindings` to display the generated bindings.

If you want to use `srun`, then there are plenty of other options. If you are playing around with Intel MPI, then you could use `I_MPI_PIN_PROCESSOR_LIST` environmental variable.

Comment: This will not work, because each mpirun would use both sockets at the same time. So it will end up in two oversubscribed sets of 32 tasks each.

Comment: Have you tried with `-nooversubscribe` ? Additionally you are also mentioning `#SBATCH --cores-per-socket`. So did you verify the bindings with `-report-bindings`?

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but even `--no-oversubscribe` will not work; because the first mpirun would occupy the whole 32 cores resource and would not leave any free cores for the second one. 

Moreover, tasks of a single mpirun shall not distribute between two sockets, cause that increase communication and reduce performance.

All I want is simple; code_1.py on socket 0 and code_2 on socket 1. Very simple, but difficult to understand how to do it.

I am aware of `-report-bindings`, but non of the flags aforementioned would give me the desired result.

Comment: Strange indeed. In theory it should work. ‘mpirun -n 16 --map-by ppr:16:socket --no-oversubscribe python code_1.py &
mpirun -n 16 --map-by ppr:16:socket --no-oversubscribe python code_2.py  & wait‘. Can you add wait at the end and see what happens.